# How to install Zend Framework on Linux CentOS

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos5

I have a VPS server and I need to install the Zend Framework for its Google client library.

I am confused as to whether I can install Zend for particular site or if I need to install as the root user so it will be available for all websites on that Linux server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to **install** it. Zend Framework is just a bunch of php scripts in general. So download it, unpack it anywhere you want and `include` (or `require`, doesn't matter) necessary classes.

Answer (score 1):

for centos 6

1. install epel repository: rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
2. install ZendFramework: yum install php-ZendFramework

Comment: While this is easy (I just did it) note that it installs the minimum version which doesn't include all data adapters.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to install Zend Framework 1 on an old CentOS 5 server in order to support web applications built using Zend Framework. Since there’s no RPM available for RHEL 5, I had to manually install the package but I’ll include details for installing via RPM on CentOS 6.

### Manual Installation

Note: I usually log in as a regular (non-super) user and use `sudo` for
administrative tasks.

Download the zip archive into your home directory and unzip it:

```
tar xvzf ZendFramework-version.tar.gz
```

Create a directory for PHP applications in `/usr/local/share`. According to
the *Filesystem Hierarchy Standard* (see `man hier`), `/usr/local/share` is
for:

> Local application data that can be shared among different architectures of
>   the same OS

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/php
```

*Note*: the `-p` option won’t produce an error if the directory already exists.

Copy the Zend Framework library into this directory:

```
sudo mv ~/ZendFramework-version/ /usr/local/share/php/Zend
```

Create a symbolic link for the `zf` command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/php/Zend/bin/zf.sh /usr/local/bin/zf
```

Finally, add the Zend library to PHP’s `include_path` (and restart the web
server so it uses the new PHP configuration):

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/share/php/Zend/library"
```

### Install using RPM for RHEL 6

Packages for RHEL 6 /CentOS 6 are available in the [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

- `php-ZendFramework`: basic Zend Framework
- `php-ZendFramework2` : Zend Framework 2
- `php-ZendFramework-full`: Meta package to install full Zend Framework; this installs a much larger set of packages (Zend Framework components and PHP modules).

The minimal install requires the `php-bcmath` and `php-process` packages.

- The library code is installed to `/usr/share/php/Zend`.
- The `zf` command is installed to `/usr/bin/zf` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/php/Zend/zf.sh`.

If you don’t already have the EPEL repository installed, the CentOS Extras repository includes a package to install the EPEL repository (enabled by default).

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

After adding the EPEL repository, I usually configure it to be disabled by default so if I’m installing a package, the standard repositories are used; if I want to install a package from an EPEL repository, I explicitly do so in my `yum` commands. This is done by setting `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`.

Install preferred Zend Framework package:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install php-ZendFramework
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install php-ZendFramework2
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install php-ZendFramework-full
```

Comment: epel give error while installing  php-ZendFramework2.
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64

Comment: @vidurpunj You'll have to decide whether you'd prefer to use the ZendFramework2 package or the Webtatic 5.6. From experience, I can say that it's a lot more work to build PHP from source than it is to manually install a library such as Zend Framework.